# How may i amend the code so that both html and jscript is working at the same time, when the background is changed during the seasons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i I make it so that the background wallpaper will be at a fixed location and scaled to the window of the browser when it is opened? I want the background to change to match the seasons of the year.

```
<html>
<head>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>TWGSB Departments</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#fsbg {
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: -100;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1040px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var north = true;
var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
if (today.getDate() > 20) month++;
var backImg = ['summer.jpg','autumn.jpg','winter.jpg','spring.jpg'];
document.getElementsByTagName('body').item('0').style.backgroundImage = 
'url('+backImg[Math.floor((month+(north?6:0))/3)%4]+')';
</script>
</body>

</html><img        src="images/summer.jpg","images/autumn.jpg","images/winter.jpg","images/spring.jpg", name="fsbg" width="1920" height="1200" id="fsbg">
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
```

Comment: Start by fixing your HTML. You have `<html>` and `<head>` before the `<!doctype>`, and a second `<html>` after it.

Comment: Would someone be able to edit the code for me? I'm a novice at this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your HTML. If you fix them you can use `background-size: cover` to cover the the element and `background-position: center center` to center the background in the element.

It could look something like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4RXzN/1/)**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the js script worked very well!